# How to make basic code autocompletion?

Tags: gtk, code-completion, gtksourceview

I'm making simple code editor in GTK and gtksourceview2.0. I would like to add to my editor a code completion window. There should be 10-15 keywords (always the same).

Can anyone could give me url for some tutorials or describe usage of gtk_source_completion_XXX functions?

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, you could do [what ccSadegh said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361143/how-to-make-basic-code-autocompletion/3543827#3543827). Or you could just use [GtkSourceCompletion](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/GtkSourceCompletion.html).

Comment: Can GtkSourceCompletion also automatically complete parantheses, brackets, and so on?

Answer (score 6):

What you need is to parse the user input by the `key-press-event` signal (or similar signals).

- Get the *GtkTextBuffer* by calling gtk_text_view_get_buffer.
- Get the *GtkTextMark* by calling gtk_text_buffer_get_insert.
- Get the *GtkTextIter* by calling gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark.
- Check if the *GtkTextIter* is at the end of the word by gtk_text_iter_ends_word.
- If it was

  - then Use gtk_text_iter_backward_word_start to get the GtkTextIter for the start of the word.
  - Call gtk_text_buffer_get_text to get the uncompleted word.
  - Search for related identifiers and display them in a GtkTreeView on a GtkWindow of GTK_WINDOW_POPUP type.

If you want to show the auto-complete list after `.` or `::` or `->`, then you should get the previous word by an approach like the above.